# Javascript not working in rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

> Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-11
>   17:59:52 +0200 Served asset /jquery.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
>
> Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-11
>   17:59:52 +0200 Served asset /jquery_ujs.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
>
> Started GET
>   "/assets/jquery-fileupload/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js?body=1" for
>   127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-11 17:59:53 +0200 Served asset /jquery-fileupload/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
>
> Started GET
>   "/assets/jquery-fileupload/jquery.iframe-transport.js?body=1" for
>   127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-11 17:59:53 +0200 Served asset /jquery-fileupload/jquery.iframe-transport.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
>
> Started GET "/assets/jquery-fileupload/jquery.fileupload.js?body=1"
>   for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-11 17:59:53 +0200 Served asset
>   /jquery-fileupload/jquery.fileupload.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
>
> Started GET "/assets/jquery-fileupload/basic.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1
>   at 2013-04-11 17:59:53 +0200 Served asset /jquery-fileupload/basic.js
>   - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
>
> Started GET "/assets/jquery-fileupload/vendor/tmpl.js?body=1" for
>   127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-11 17:59:53 +0200 Served asset /jquery-fileupload/vendor/tmpl.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
>
> Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-transition.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at
>   2013-04-11 17:59:53 +0200 Served asset /bootstrap-transition.js - 304
>   Not Modified (0ms)
>
> Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-affix.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at
>   2013-04-11 17:59:53 +0200 Served asset /bootstrap-affix.js - 304 Not
>   Modified (0ms)
>
> Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-alert.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at
>   2013-04-11 17:59:53 +0200 Served asset /bootstrap-alert.js - 304 Not
>   Modified (0ms)
>
> Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-button.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at
>   2013-04-11 17:59:53 +0200 Served asset /bootstrap-button.js - 304 Not
>   Modified (0ms)
>
> Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-carousel.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at
>   2013-04-11 17:59:53 +0200 Served asset /bootstrap-carousel.js - 304
>   Not Modified (0ms)
>
> Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-collapse.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at
>   2013-04-11 17:59:53 +0200 Served asset /bootstrap-collapse.js - 304
>   Not Modified (0ms)

Any ideas on what this is?

Comment: An HTTP log with lots of cache?

Comment: what is the js error where is js code

Comment: So this is probably not the source of my problem?

Comment: may be you need to update the version info of the js if u have made any change ,using bootstrap-collapse.js?version=3.5

Comment: @masb, Most definitely not a problem there.

Comment: @masb we don't know what your problem is. If you were concerned about what specifically the logs meant, that's what you should have said in your question. If you just thought in general that the logs may mean an error, that's too vague a question. If something is wrong, tell us what's actually wrong.

Comment: Figured it out. Found the solution in another tread.

Answer (score 0):

it's working. it's just that the client already has your file and there's no reason to resend it so it's just sending a 304 code. you can explicitly set headers to deny the browsers from caching it and then it will always come for the latest version.